# Intelij Properties editor

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I'm using below intelij version with properties bundle installed.

```
Build #IC-221.5080.210, built on April 12, 2022
    
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. 

Properties Plugin -> bundled 221.5080.210
```

When i try to edit the properties, as shown in the below image some of the properties are greyed out though they are not commented. Does anyone has such issue? any workarounds please?

[image]

Comment: Is it Srping project? Do you have these properties used anywhere? How do you connect minio to your project?

Comment: Most likely IntelliJ IDEA considers your properties unused and highlights them as such. You can turn off the unused property inspection in Settings | Inspections if the inspection does not work properly in your use case.

Comment: Yep that's right i have disabled in inspections and it serves my purpose thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA considers your properties unused and highlights them as such. You can turn off the unused property inspection in Settings | Inspections if the inspection does not work properly in your use case.